# Each row as PartialView in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, devexpress

We have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses gridview (from DevExpress MVC) control as PartialView. This gridview contains milions of rows, and after doing some action whole partialview is updated using ajax which takes a lot of time. Is there any possibilty to update only single row using ajax?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

At present, No. The GridView should be defined within a separate [PartialView](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9052) and the whole PartialView should be updated after a grid callback (via the result of the [CallbackRouteValues.Action](http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcGridViewSettings_CallbackRouteValuestopic)).